# Layout alignment Query {Center Horizontal + Center Vertical}

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Must be very simple to solve but I'm not able to solve this.

I want to align the "top image and log_in_box", so the whole thing appear in exact center (Horizontal+Vertical center) of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/log_in_box" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="User ID"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Password" android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <CheckBox android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true"
                android:text="Remember Me" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/log_in" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Log In" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Current Look**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/log_in_box" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="User ID"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Password" android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <CheckBox android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true"
                android:text="Remember Me" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/log_in" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Log In" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 Your answer is correct but android:orientation="vertical" is required on outer (first) LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/log_in_box" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="User ID"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Password" android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <CheckBox android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true"
            android:text="Remember Me" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/log_in" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="Log In" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. Your answer is also correct but replace android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" with android:layout_centerInParent="true".

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="User ID"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Remember Me" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log_in"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Log In" />
```